# Object defined error

Tags: excel, vba

I am using excel 2007. I am using a macro which copies all visible sheets to new workbook and saves at as text files. I have more than 12 sheets from which i have to copy at least 10 sheets. 4 visible sheets are copies but on the fifth sheet i got an error of Application_defined or Object_defined error. I have tables in other six sheets . please help me solve this problem.

```
Sub day_end_process()

'Working in 97-2010
Dim FileExtStr As String
Dim FileFormatNum As Long
Dim Sourcewb As Workbook
Dim Destwb As Workbook
Dim sh As Worksheet
Dim DateString As String
Dim FolderName As String

'Copy every sheet from the workbook with this macro
Set Sourcewb = ThisWorkbook

'Create new folder to save the new files in
DateString = Format(Now, "yyyy-mm-dd hh-mm-ss")
FolderName = Sourcewb.path & "\" & Sourcewb.Name & " " & DateString
MkDir FolderName

'Copy every visible sheet to a new workbook
For Each sh In Sourcewb.Worksheets

    'If the sheet is visible then copy it to a new workbook
    If sh.Visible = -1 Then
        sh.Copy

        'Set Destwb to the new workbook
        Set Destwb = ActiveWorkbook

        'Determine the Excel version and file extension/format
        With Destwb
            FileExtStr = ".txt": FileFormatNum = -4158
        End With

        'Change all cells in the worksheet to values if you want
        'I get error in this if statement.

        If Destwb.Sheets(1).ProtectContents = False Then
            With Destwb.Sheets(1).UsedRange
                .Cells.Copy
                .Cells.PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
                .Cells(1).Select
            End With
            Application.CutCopyMode = False
        End If
        'Save the new workbook and close it
        With Destwb
            .SaveAs FolderName _
                  & "\" & Destwb.Sheets(1).Name & FileExtStr, _
                    FileFormat:=FileFormatNum
            .Close False
        End With
    End If
GoToNextSheet:
Next sh
MsgBox "You can find the files in " & FolderName
Sheets("Main Page").Select
With Application
    .ScreenUpdating = True
    .EnableEvents = True
    .Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
End With
Sheets("Main Page").Select
ActiveWorkbook.Save

End Sub
```

Comment: is there something specific in the 5th workbook that would cause it to err? Also, in this statement `Set Destwb = ActiveWorkbook` where are you actually creating a new workbook? According to your code, I can't distinguish why the ActiveWorkbook would be any different from the source workbook which holds the code.

Comment: As above there must be something in sheet 5 that's causing issues, on which line does the error occur? @ScottHoltzman the sheet copy command copies the sheet to a new workbook which then becomes the active workbook

Comment: @Kyle - Thanks. I overlooked that!

Comment: @ScottHoltzman I am guessing sheet 5 may be the first invisible sheet. If the first 4 work fine then the problem must occur with the `If` conditional statement because its the only change in the code path.

Comment: Are all the sheets worksheets - no chart sheets?

Answer (score 1):

in place of

```
    If Destwb.Sheets(1).ProtectContents = False Then 
        With Destwb.Sheets(1).UsedRange 
            .Cells.Copy 
            .Cells.PasteSpecial xlPasteValues 
            .Cells(1).Select 
        End With 
        Application.CutCopyMode = False 
    End If
```

Maybe try:

```
    If Destwb.Sheets(1).ProtectContents = False Then 
        Destwb.Sheets(1).UsedRange.value = Destwb.Sheets(1).UsedRange.value 
    End If
```